# Появляется аудио на хостинге

Tags: javascript, laravel, аудио, взлом

В коде нет упоминания про ДАННОЕ аудио(как на скрине), откуда[image: ссылка на хостинге] оно берется на хостинге?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/1230286

Comment: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/2552

Comment: Но у меня не через cdn подключается

Comment: А cdn тут абсолютно ни при чём

Comment: Понял,  сспасибо